# Expose Meta Link on MSE's New Upper Tab

Tags: support, user-interface, top-bar

In the new MSE tab, the link to Meta for me is hidden under "help" which requires the click of the downarrow. How can I pin it to the upper tab to avoid these 2 clicks?

Comment: It's also hidden under the "StackExchange" link, so if you get tired of using the "help" link, there is an option.

Answer (score 2):

In my browser (Firefox), I can drag either link (from the "StackExchange" menu or the "help" menu) to my bookmark bar. Also, right-clicking on either link might allow you to move the meta link to the bookmark bar.

Comment: Or else just manually add links to `http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/` and `http://math.stackexchange.com/` to your bookmark toolbar.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: that might work, too :-)

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Thanks. However, can I pin it to the MSE upper tab and not my Internet browser's bookmarks?

Comment: @LePressentiment: There is a [StackApp](http://stackapps.com/q/4411/21184) (user script) currently in development that should allow users to change the look and feel of the toolbar.  I have not used it, and it is not officially endorsed by SE.  But it does claim to be able to add the meta/main links.

Comment: @LePressentiment: I don't believe so. I don't know if the developers would want to implement a feature that is part of most browsers, but you could tag this question with [tag:feature-request] (or try Arthur Fischer's suggestion).

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Thank you. I asked this because the "meta" link was right on the old MSE tab so didn't have to click twice. Was it so for you too?

Comment: @LePressentiment: Yes, in the old top-bar the links to meta/main were clearly available on it.  Since I move between the sites quite frequently, I greatly preferred the old way.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Yes, me equally. So for the meta link to be readded, I'd have to wait for the StackApp adverted to in your above comment?

Comment: @LePressentiment: You can try this StackApp now.  I haven't used it, but it seems like you should now be able to use the one that adds the meta/main links.  And you can follow MSO feature requests to bring them back by default [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210022/214632) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207423/214632).

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

For an alternative option, the "Community Bulletin" section on the right hand side of the page provides several links to the meta page. (click on "meta", not on the topic name)

Comment: Nice! Do you by any chance know of easy way to go in the opposite direction, from Meta to Main?

Comment: Nope. Well, yes: in chrome, I can do "Alt+d", "m", "Enter", but that's rather dependent on my browsing habits.